What does ガったれちゃって mean?
In the song Nobosemon HERO by ChibaNyan and Giga, there's a lyrics that goes

ガったれちゃって

I can't seem to find a translation for it. I can tell that it's probably and abbreviation of ガったれてしまって, shortening it to ガったれて, but that's still not enough for any online dictionary to recognize it as a word. The bets translation I could find was "I'm shooting glares", but I still can't figure out the dictionary form of the verb to confirm this.

Original MV & full lyrics for context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM5mzW3pgh4

のぼせもん, ずんだれる, ちかっぱ, なかろーもん and so on in the lyrics are northern Kyushu dialect expressions, so がったれる should be in Kyushu dialect, too. (The female singer, ずんだもん, is known as a Tohoku-ben speaker, but she is using Kyushu-ben for some reason in the song.)
I couldn't find the definition of がったれる itself, but according to several sources online, がんたれる exists in Kyushu dialects, and it means something along the lines of うまくいってない, ダメだ or 役に立っていない.

"さなえの鹿児島弁講座" 『ずんだれ がんたれ あまったれ』
鹿児島弁と思いますが（がんたれ）とはなんですか？
がんたれ | 宮崎弁データベース

I might be wrong, but I imagine ガったれちゃって is used like "You're no fun" or "You're such a buzzkill" in the context of the lyrics. I don't know the etymology of がんたれ, but ガン is widely recognized as an intensifier prefix, so replacing it with ガっ wouldn't change the feeling of the word at least in my perception.

Would this be がん or がっ + たれる as in 垂れる, and the root of 怠い【だるい】?

@EiríkrÚtlendi That's likely but I cannot ssy anything for sure.
